# Add TextField in a ButtonBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I used `ButtonBar` to arrange button in a row inside a `Column`.

In the ButtonBar I have put a TextField:

```
              ButtonBar
              (
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>
                [
                  Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                         maxLines: 8,
                         decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Enter your text here"),
                      ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

This ButtonBar is in a Column. I am able to display normal buttons and text this way. Only this TextField is creating problems:

```
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#3888e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
TextField
lib/main.dart:138`
```

Comment: try replacing expanded with flexible or wrap expanded (or flexible) with a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
SizedBox(
      height: 40,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `TextField` in `ConstrainedBox`, like this:

```
ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
         maxHeight: 40 ,
         maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
         ),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: This worked. This `width` property for `ConstrainedBox` is not being accepted by Flutter. I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Please use put Textfield in Container and give them width and height
like this :

```
ButtonBar(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: 200,
                  child: TextField(
                    maxLines: 8,
                    decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                        hintText: "Enter your text here"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```